# How do I populate a slice with interfaces?

Tags: go, interface, slice

I know I can populate a Go slice with strings with `strings := []string{"something", "something else"}`, but how can I do the same except with interfaces? I've tried the following:

```
data := []interface{}{{ID: "123"}, {ID: "456"}}
```

And got the following error:

```
missing type in composite literal
```

I've also tried to use a struct like so:

```
type Users struct {
    ID string
}

[]Users{{ID: "123"}, {ID: "456"}}
```

Which works, but `mongo`'s [`InsertMany`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc#Collection.InsertMany) function needs a `[]interface{}` parameter:

```
cannot use users (type []Users) as type []interface {} in argument to database.InsertMany
```

How can I define and populate a `[]interface{}`?

Comment: @MuffinTop Ah my bad, edited

Comment: You must declare the element types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, you're missing the type in your composite literal:

```
data := []interface{}{Users{ID: "123"}, Users{ID: "456"}}
```

should work, as it is not missing the types from the composite literals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm new to golang, sorry about that. I'll accept this after the 10 minute timer

Answer (score 1):

`[]interface{}` and `[]Users` are different types in Go.

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice

So you can either initialize your slice as in Adrian's answer or you can create slice of interfaces from slice of Users like this

```
users := []Users{{ID: "123"}, {ID: "456"}}
usersInterfaces := make([]interface{}, len(users))

for i, u := range users {
    usersInterfaces[i] = u
}
```